# PHP and SQL filter

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code where I do a search from PHP on my SQL on a parameter between two dates.

```
"SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE date >=  '" . $dates . "' 
AND date <= '" . $datee . "' AND msisdn='$query'"
```

What I want to do is use this to search on the current date as far as I understand it is date() but it is not working and not showing me results for the SQL entered on the current date.

```
"SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE date =  '" . date() . "' 
 AND msisdn='$query'"
```

This is what I attempting

Comment: you could do something like this `SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE date =  '" . date('Y-m-d') . "' 
 AND msisdn='$query'`

Answer (score 0):

Try `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` instead if you want to use php date.

Or use `NOW()` directly in sql

Comment: ("SELECT * FROM e_track_access_log WHERE member_id>0 AND datetime_accessed = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ORDER BY datetime_accessed DESC LIMIT 0,20") 

Does not show any results at all

Comment: @MaggieAckermann, `date` is a php function, so: `"SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE date =  '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "' 
 AND msisdn='$query'"`

Comment: "SELECT * FROM e_track_access_log WHERE member_id>0 AND datetime_accessed = '" . date('Y-m-d') . "' ORDER BY datetime_accessed DESC LIMIT 0,20"

Also not working No results shown

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) and for diff in date you have to use `BETWEEN` in mysql:

```
"SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE date between CURDATE() AND $datee  AND msisdn='$query'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to use the NOW() or CURDATE() functions of mysql itself:

```
SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE date = now() AND msisdn='$query'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE date = CURDATE() AND msisdn='$query'
```

Comment: have you tried checking your SQL query straight on the database? And try echo'ing your query in your PHP script to see if the result is a viable query. Most often your resulting query looks something like AND msisdn='-0235654' while you expect it to be 0235654 for instance, or even simply null (''), which will also yield no results.

Comment: Would it be that the column is not a date time setting and set to Var?

Comment: And what exactly is the content of that column? You might indeed have to format your datefunction differently.

Comment: Try this: WHERE substring(date, 1, 10) = curdate()

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using mysql build in method:

```
"SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE date = CURDATE() AND msisdn='$query'"
```